# How to align react-tabs vertically with the content appearing to the left of each tab?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-tabs

I am having a react-tab component with custom css applied to it.I need to align the tablist vertically and the  tab panel should be aligned to the right of the tabs,

the css i have used is,

```css
.react-tabs__tab-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 12rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;

  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  /* margin: 1rem; */
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  /* display: inline-block; */

  border: none;
}

.react-tabs__tab-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 12rem;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.react-tabs__tab-panel > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.react-tabs__tab-list > div {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.react-tabs__tab-list li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ededed;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.react-tabs__tab-list .react-tabs__tab--selected {
  background: #ededed;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #0b1e2e;
}

.react-tabs__tab-list .react-tabs__tab--selected:focus {
  background: #70ceea;
  color: #0b1e2e;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.react-tabs__tab:focus:after {
  background: #ededed;
}

.react-tabs__tab-panel--selected {
  -webkit-animation: 800ms ease-in-out 0s normal none 1 running customOne;
  animation: 800ms ease-in-out 0s normal none 1 running customOne;
}
```

my component page looks like this,

```js
<Tabs selectedIndex={tabIndex} onSelect={(index) => setTabIndex(index)}>
  <TabList>
    <Tab >Title 1</Tab>
    <Tab>Title 2</Tab>
    <Tab >Title 3</Tab>
  </TabList>
  <TabPanel>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </TabPanel>
  <TabPanel>panel2</TabPanel>
</Tabs>
```

some how i was not able to achieve this view in the UI.Is there a custom props which can be given to Tabs to do this,or does changing the css can do this .